# How to start developing with Twitter for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to bb app development. Now I'm supposed to develop a Twitter application for blackberry. How do I start my application.. is there any Twitter API for blackberry?

I have created the UI of the login page, but how to start with authenticating username and password? I have registered my app in twitter now I have the consumer key and secret, but I dont know how to use that.

Anyone knows about twitter apps for blackberry or have any sample code for Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [TwitterAPIMe](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home).

You may find how to use the API in the link.

I used it, it's easy and working well with good performance.

PS, you must be RIM4.6 or higher

Comment: thank u.. but i have taken the sample from there only. but i am able to login after login page i am getting illegal exception. actually i have to tweet after login..